# Запись символа в конец строки - C (СИ)

Tags: c

Работающая программа для нахождения самого длинного слова в тексте. Но хотелось бы, чтобы она параллельно записывала самое длинное слово.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned short main() {

FILE *fl;

char ch;
unsigned char bword;
unsigned char maxword = 0;
unsigned char lenword = 0;

fl = fopen("Ekz1.txt","r");

   if (fl == NULL) 
       {
          perror("Error in opening file");
          return(-1);
       }

    while (!(feof(fl)) )
       {
        ch=fgetc(fl);

            if (((ch >= 'A')&&(ch <= 'Z')) || ((ch >= 'a')&&(ch <= 'z'))) 
             {   
                bword = 1;
             } 
             else
                bword = 0;

        if (bword == 1)    
        lenword+=1;
        else if((bword == 0)&&(lenword != 0)&&(lenword >= maxword))
            {          
               maxword = lenword;
               lenword = 0;
               sf[50]=st[50];
               st[50]=" ";
            }
            else lenword = 0;
   }

printf("%d", maxword);
fclose(fl);
return (0);
}
```

Comment: У Вас не указано что за массивы `sf` и `st` и где массив `st` заполняется

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так, сохраняя его (заодно подчистил ваш код).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define  MAX_WORD_SIZE  100

unsigned short main()
{
    FILE* fl;
    int ch;
    unsigned int maxword = 0;
    unsigned int lenword = 0;
    char maxstr[MAX_WORD_SIZE] = { 0 };
    char tmpstr[MAX_WORD_SIZE] = { 0 };
    fl = fopen("Ekz1.txt", "r");

    if (fl == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error in opening file");
        return (-1);
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(fl)) != EOF)
    {
        if (((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z')) || ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')))
        {
            tmpstr[lenword++] = ch;
            continue;
        }
        else if (lenword > maxword)
        {
            tmpstr[maxword = lenword] = 0;
            strcpy(maxstr,tmpstr);
        }
        memset(tmpstr,0,MAX_WORD_SIZE);
        lenword = 0;
    }

    printf("%d - %s\n", maxword,maxstr);
    fclose(fl);
    return (0);
}
```

Я сделал максимально просто - через массив фиксированного размера `MAX_WORD_SIZE` и без проверки выхода за пределы массива - просто, чтоб показать принцип.